# Implement a load and list function

Tags: java, list, load

I have been given this piece of pre set code by my uni and have been told to implement a load method and a list method from it. However I am currently unsure of how to fill in the blanks. I usually am not to bad at programming however the stress of meeting the deadline has caused me to forget simple little things.This is the final part of the 1st increment of my project.

How would I would implement a load and list method to get the file customers.txt.

```
  public static List<Customer> loadCustomers() {
    List<Customer> customers = null; 

    System.out.println("loadCustomers");
    return customers;
}
```

I also have the follwing at the top of my class

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner (System.in);
    char choice;

    List<Customer> customers=loadCustomers();
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ["Questions asking for homework help must include a **summary of the work you've done so far** to solve the problem, and a **description of the difficulty you are having** solving it."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: i will edit the question

Comment: You should also take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the documentation in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).  In particular, you should read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what sorts of questions are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here at SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand this correctly. I am guessing there are two different things:

1. Loading the list of customers from `customers.txt` into a list
2. Returning that list of customers back in this method.

To solve this, you will have to analytically solve using these steps:

1. Open and parse the `customers.txt` file
2. For each customer, add them to your `customers` list
3. After you have finished reading the last line (or last customer) on your file, close the file, and return the list.

You will have to demonstrate what you have already done in your attempts to solve this question - so I won't post any code yet. But the above workflow tells you how to tackle this question.

Also, not sure why the method signature needs to be static - nothing bad- but why is it an instance method?

Comment: Yes that is the way i would like it to work. So far I tried using a buffered reader to read my specified document. It reads the file however it doesn't effect my program from within the confides of the pre set code I was given.